# Insertion in Heap in java

Tags: java, data-structures, heap

Here is an implementation of a Heap in java without using array but I have some problem in inserting data in it for example when i insert 1,3,2,5,8 it inserts 5,8 two times one as subtree of 3 and another one as subtree of 2.

```
public class Heap {
private class Node {
    private Node left, right,parent;
    private int key;
    private Node(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}

private Node root;

public void insert(int key) {
     root = insert(root,key,null);
}

private Node insert(Node x, int key,Node parent) {
    if(x == null){
        x = new Node(key);
        x.parent = parent;
        return x;
    }if(x.left == null){
        x.left = insert(x.left, key,x);
    }else if (x.right == null) {
        x.right = insert(x.right, key,x);
    }else{
        x.left = insert(x.left, key,x);
        x.right = insert(x.right, key,x);
    }
    return x;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @MikkelLøkke The problem specification is clear enough: a test case and actual behavior, where the expected behavior is inherent to what OP is trying to implement.

Comment: Do you really need insert to return Node? And why replacing root in `insert`?

Comment: OP, you must ensure the *heap property*: the child must be smaller than the parent. What you are doing now is just a haphazard tree with no invariant holding on it. Once you think about that and solve it, the immediate problem that you are inserting indiscriminately to left and right should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is

```
x.left = insert(x.left, key,x);
x.right = insert(x.right, key,x);
```

you are simply inserting to both sub heaps...

This is not how heap works...

Comment: how can i correct this?I also want to have a nearly complete binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
    x.left = insert(x.left, key, x);
    x.right = insert(x.right, key, x);
}
```

inserts the key in both sub-trees of x.

You have to decide which branch to take, e.g. by comparing the key to the key at x, and using the right branch if `key >= x.key`, otherwise take the left branch (if done properly you'll get an ordered tree), or take the branch which is the smallest sub-tree of x.

Comment: But he do not want binary tree, but heap, keys are irrelevant for finding proper branch...

Comment: The primary suspicious thing here is the absence of any comparison at all---obviously OP is not maintaining the heap property.

Comment: @Betlista a heap is a tree with some kind of relation between the elements, e.g. a max heap stores the largest values at the top of the tree.

Comment: I know well how heap works, but you are not choosing right or left branch with respect to key value. In array implementation it is added to the end (simplified, always put to left subtree if not full) and value is important when maintaining heap property...